# Activate extension programmatically with a command execution

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'd like to activate extension A from extension B with a help of a command that extension A defines. This command is also an activation event for extension A, i.e. "trigger.command"
Therefore if from extension B I call `VScode.commands.executeCommand("trigger.command")` will that activate extension A?
If not, is there anything else I can try doing?

Answer (score 0):

If the command actually runs, I don't see how this cannot activate the extension. It must to run the code. See [VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#commands.executeCommand).